# Data not updating on pressing back button

Tags: android

I am making a note taking app using Shared Preferences. However when I click on a listItem to edit it, and click back again, it isn't being updated.

My MainActivity with the list view :

```
ListView notesListView;
static ArrayList<String> notesArrayList;
static ArrayAdapter<String> notesAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    notesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    notesArrayList.add("Example");

    notesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notesArrayList);

    notesListView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);

    notesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditNote.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And my edit note activity:

```
EditText userNote;
int noteId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_note);

    userNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNote);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    noteId = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1);
    if(noteId != -1){

        userNote.setText(MainActivity.notesArrayList.get(noteId));

    }
    userNote.addTextChangedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent goBack = new Intent(EditNote.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(goBack);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        MainActivity.notesArrayList.set(noteId, String.valueOf(s));
        MainActivity.notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
}
```

I think the problem lies in the onBackPressed in Edit Note. However I would like a solution as I fail to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all in your this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent goBack = new Intent(EditNote.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(goBack);
    finish();
}
```

change it to this

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {  
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
```

because why are you starting `MainActivity.java` again when you are already going to `MainActivity.java` on simply `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ironman. Yeah I overlooked it. Silly mistake. However when the `MainActivity.java` gets created again, shouldn't it make a new **Example Note** as well?

Comment: @AkhileshChobey you can accept the answer if it useful to you.

Comment: @AkhileshChobey glad to help you.